# Combining two regular expressions with different grouping requirements

Tags: python, regex

I have two different repeated character substitution rules I'd like to combine into one regex.

I can do this in python 3.x:

```
import re
s = r'http://www.google.com/search=ooo-eeee-aa-ii-uuuu'
aiu=re.compile(r'(([aiu])\2{1,})')
eo=re.compile(r'(([eo])\2{2,})')
eo.sub(r'\2',aiu.sub(r'\2',s))
```

IF there is a major performance gain (this operation will be applied millions of times), is there a single regex expression that achieves what these two achieve (without having to nest calls like I did above).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because since the code works it should be posted on [codereview.se].

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew while this post might be on-topic on CR with a little more context, please don't use the existence of that site as a reason to VTC.  Instead use a reason like **Needs more focus**. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353), [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [_A guide to CR for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two substitutions with an alternation pattern. The replacement string can be both `\1` and `\2` together, since one of them will be empty and not affect the output anyway.

```
aeiou = re.compile(r'([aiu])\1{1,}|([eo])\2{2,}')
aeiou.sub(r'\1\2', s)
```

Comment: Your idea is right (though you forgot to enclose the right side of the first line inside a call to re.compile()

Thank you for being helpful.

Comment: Oops forgot to add that when I edited my answer to mimic your code. Fixed then. Thanks.